# Transform-duration is not working in Safari, but is working in Chrome

Tags: css, css-transitions

```
.cl-effect-10 a::before {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    height: 40px;
    width: 10px;
    background:#00BFFF;
    color: #ddd;
    content: attr(data-hover);
    -webkit-transition-property: width; 
    -webkit-transition-duration: 2s; 
    -webkit-transform: skew(-45deg, 0);
    -moz-transform: skew(-45deg, 0);
    -ms-transform: skew(-45deg, 0);
    transform: skew(-45deg, 0);
}
.cl-effect-10 a:hover::before,.cl-effect-10 a:focus::before {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Transform-duration is not working in Safari, but is working in Chrome.
I would like to ask you for any kind of help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of Safari are you testing in? How can you tell that it's just the `transition-duration` property that isn't being applied and not all the `transition`properties?

Comment: My Safair is version 5.1.7, you are right, This is a question of version. thans your advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prior to version 6.1, Safari did not support `transition` on `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements ([source](https://css-tricks.com/transitions-and-animations-on-css-generated-content/)) so, if you're testing in an older version than that, that will account for your problem.

Incidentally, using the CSS provided in your question, your transitions will only work in Chrome & Safari as you are only using the `-webkit-` prefixed version of the properties. Almost all browsers (with one exception) that support CSS transitions now support them, and have for some time, without the need for any prefixing. However, if you need to provide support for older browsers, use [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions)'s tables to determine which prefixes you might need to use.